# naming exception with EJB

Tags: java, ejb, javabeans

I'm trying to follow an online tutorial and although I'm sure the writers of the tutorial know what they are doing, I keep getting an exception upon execution.

Remote Interface

```
package com.tutorialspoint.stateless;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface LibrarySessionBeanRemote {
   void addBook(String bookName);
   List getBooks();
}
```

Stateless EJB

```
package com.tutorialspoint.stateless;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class LibrarySessionBean implements LibrarySessionBeanRemote {

   List<String> bookShelf;    

   public LibrarySessionBean(){
      bookShelf = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   public void addBook(String bookName) {
      bookShelf.add(bookName);
   }    

   public List<String> getBooks() {
      return bookShelf;
   }
}
```

jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost
```

tester

```
package com.tutorialspoint.test;

import com.tutorialspoint.stateful.LibrarySessionBeanRemote;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class EJBTester {

   BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null; 
   Properties props;
   InitialContext ctx;
   {
      props = new Properties();
      try {
         props.load(new FileInputStream("jndi.properties"));
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
         ctx = new InitialContext(props);            
      } catch (NamingException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      brConsoleReader = 
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      EJBTester ejbTester = new EJBTester();

      ejbTester.testStatelessEjb();
   }

   private void showGUI(){
      System.out.println("**********************");
      System.out.println("Welcome to Book Store");
      System.out.println("**********************");
      System.out.print("Options \n1. Add Book\n2. Exit \nEnter Choice: ");
   }

   private void testStatelessEjb(){

      try {
         int choice = 1; 

         LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean =
         LibrarySessionBeanRemote)ctx.lookup("LibrarySessionBean/remote");

         while (choice != 2) {
            String bookName;
            showGUI();
            String strChoice = brConsoleReader.readLine();
            choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);
            if (choice == 1) {
               System.out.print("Enter book name: ");
               bookName = brConsoleReader.readLine();
               Book book = new Book();
               book.setName(bookName);
               libraryBean.addBook(book);          
            } else if (choice == 2) {
               break;
            }
         }

         List<Book> booksList = libraryBean.getBooks();

         System.out.println("Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList.size());
         int i = 0;
         for (Book book:booksList) {
            System.out.println((i+1)+". " + book.getName());
            i++;
         }       
         LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean1 = 
            (LibrarySessionBeanRemote)ctx.lookup("LibrarySessionBean/remote");
         List<String> booksList1 = libraryBean1.getBooks();
         System.out.println(
            "***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***");
         System.out.println(
            "Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList1.size());
         for (int i = 0; i < booksList1.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println((i+1)+". " + booksList1.get(i));
         }       
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally {
         try {
            if(brConsoleReader !=null){
               brConsoleReader.close();
            }
         } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
null
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at test.EJBTester.<init>(EJBTester.java:33)
    at test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.EJBTester.testStatelessEjb(EJBTester.java:56)
    at test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:44)
```

your help will be very appreciated!
D

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory' it seems to be that you haven't add the requeried dependecies jar file to the  client classpath.

Comment: @GabrielAramburu the tutorial says: Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21 and PATH to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin which I did. it also said to add the bean to the client's library which I also did. **One more thing:** I also thought it was a versions problems so I uninstalled all jdk's and netbeans from the system and installed the the exact versions used in the tutorial... you can see the tutorial I'm referring to in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_stateful_beans.htm")

Comment: check if you did what the section "Create Client to access EJB" says: "Add jboss libraries using Add jar/folder button in compile tab. Jboss libraries can be located at <jboss installation folder>> client folder."

Comment: @GabrielAramburu : you were right! I tried adding the whole client folder and it didn't work, I now added all the jar files with Ctrl+a and added each and every one "manually" and it got the job done. you are great! thank you for staying here for me :)

Comment: @GabrielAramburu: btw I'm not sure how it works with reputation in this platform, but I can't seem to have a way to indicate your answer helped. maybe add an answer to my question so I can accept it?

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, the tutorial says I should get this: `Enter Choice: 1
Enter book name: Learn Java
**********************
Enter Choice: 2
Book(s) entered so far: 1
1. Learn Java
***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***
Book(s) entered so far: 0` **but instead I get this:** `Enter Choice: 1
Enter book name: Learn Java
**********************
Enter Choice: 2
Book(s) entered so far: 1
1. Learn Java
***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***
Book(s) entered so far: 1
1. Learn Java` **any ideas?**

Comment: I'm not sure about this, try to debug the code and ask a new question if you cant figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a remote EJB invocation, basically you need to accomplish (on the client side) the following points:

1. add to client CLASSPATH the necessary dependencis, this is:add
   the remote interfaces classes **and the server client classes.**
2. instantiate the InitialConetxt using the correct properties.
3. and provide a correct lookup name.

The stacktrace shows:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory,`

which indicates that the problem could be that the client server classes are not in the classpath.

As the tutorial indicates, the solution is:

> Add jboss libraries using Add jar/folder button in compile tab. 
>   Jboss libraries can be located at > client folder.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the code thought resolving the JNDI lookup in client would solve the problem :) that was the main problem....read my comments in client code... but as i dug more realized that this is copy paste from another training without the Book JavaBean and so on....so ended up rewriting the whole thing...

Copy the code all good to go.....
Restart the server where the EJBS' are deployed.  Run the Client with
*client*.jar[gf-client.jar in glassfish] on your classpath.

> **The interface**

```
package com.au.ejbs;

import java.util.List;

public interface LibraryI {
    void addBook(Book bookName);

    List<Book> getBooks();

    void clearShelf();
}
```

> The implementation

```
package com.au.ejbs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Remote
@Stateless
public class Library implements LibraryI {

    private List<Book> bookShelf = new ArrayList<Book>();

    @Override
    public void addBook(Book bookName) {
        bookShelf.add(bookName);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return bookShelf;
    }

    public void clearShelf(){
        if(!bookShelf.isEmpty())
        bookShelf.clear();
    }
}

package com.au.ejbs;


import javax.ejb.Remote;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

@Remote
public class Book implements Serializable {
    private String bookName;

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Book.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("bookName='" + bookName + "'")
                .toString();
    }

}
```

The Client

```
package com.au.clients;

import com.au.ejbs.Book;
import com.au.ejbs.Library;
import com.au.ejbs.LibraryI;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class LibraryT {

    BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null;
    Properties props;
    InitialContext ctx;

    {
        props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        brConsoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LibraryT LibraryT = new LibraryT();

        LibraryT.testStatelessEjb();
    }

    private void showGUI() {
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Book Store");
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.print("Options \n1. Add Book\n2. Exit \nEnter Choice: ");
    }

    private void testStatelessEjb() {
        List<Book> booksList = null;
        LibraryI libraryBean = null;
        try {
            int choice = 1;

            // LibraryI libraryBean = (LibraryI)ctx.lookup("LibrarySessionBean/remote");
            libraryBean = (LibraryI) ctx.lookup("java:global/ejb3_2_ear_exploded/ejb/Library");//Portable should work on jboss and any container , works on glassfish
              //portable syntax java:global/[ ear name]/[module name normally the jar name in my case ejb.jar within the ear, ejb3_2_ear_exploded]/Class Name of EJB impl

            while (choice != 2) {
                String bookName;
                showGUI();
                String strChoice = brConsoleReader.readLine();
                choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);
                if (choice == 1) {
                    System.out.print("Enter book name: ");
                    bookName = brConsoleReader.readLine();
                    Book book = new Book();
                    book.setBookName(bookName);
                    libraryBean.addBook(book);
                } else if (choice == 2) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            booksList = libraryBean.getBooks();

            System.out.println("Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList.size());
            int i = 0;
            for (Book book : booksList) {
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + book.getBookName());
                i++;
            }
            // LibraryI libraryBean1 = (LibraryI)ctx.lookup("LibrarySessionBean/remote");
            LibraryI libraryBean1 = (LibraryI) ctx.lookup("java:global/ejb3_2_ear_exploded/ejb/Library");//Portable should work on jboss and any container , works on glassfish
            List<Book> booksList1 = libraryBean1.getBooks();
            System.out.println(
                    "***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***");
            System.out.println(
                    "Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList1.size());
            for (i = 0; i < booksList1.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + booksList1.get(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (brConsoleReader != null) {
                    brConsoleReader.close();
                    libraryBean.clearShelf();
                }


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

config.properties

//JNDI specific to glassfish you can use the one for jboss
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447

> **The output**

```
**********************
Welcome to Book Store
**********************
Options 
1. Add Book
2. Exit 
Enter Choice: 1
Enter book name: Road Ahead
**********************
Welcome to Book Store
**********************
Options 
1. Add Book
2. Exit 
Enter Choice: 1
Enter book name: Living the Past
**********************
Welcome to Book Store
**********************
Options 
1. Add Book
2. Exit 
Enter Choice: 1
Enter book name: Enjoy the Present
**********************
Welcome to Book Store
**********************
Options 
1. Add Book
2. Exit 
Enter Choice: 2
Book(s) entered so far: 3
1. Road Ahead
2. Living the Past
3. Enjoy the Present
***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***
Book(s) entered so far: 3
1. Book[bookName='Road Ahead']
2. Book[bookName='Living the Past']
3. Book[bookName='Enjoy the Present']

Process finished with exit code 0
```